# Tell SBT to not use staging area

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to be able to compile my project once and pass it through  multiple build steps on a CI server. But SBT puts files in a staging area like the one below.

```
/home/vagrant/.sbt/0.13/staging/
```

This means the project is not stand-alone and for every CI step it is going to compile it again.

How can I tell SBT to keep things simple and stand-alone and to make sure everything it needs is inside the project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `-Dsbt.global.staging=./.staging` to sbt when starting it up, the staging directory will be `.staging` in the project's directory.

I figured that out by looking at [the sbt source](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/sxr/sbt/BuildPaths.scala.html#sbt.BuildPaths.stagingDirectory) and patching that together with how Paul P's [sbt runner](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/blob/master/sbt) passes the value for the sbt boot path.

If that doesn't accomplish what you want, then you might be able to make something go with a custom resolver. The sbt [Build Loaders](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Extending/Build-Loaders.html) page talks about creating a custom resolver that lets you specify more detail about where dependencies are written.  If my solution doesn't get you what you want, you'd probably need to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately. When I copy the folder to a new directory it tries to compile again: [info] Compiling 43 Scala sources and 1 Java source to

Comment: Which folder are you copying?

Comment: When you copy the folder, are you allowing the timestamps to update?

Comment: I'm copying the entire project folder into a new adjacent folder

Comment: Does symlinking instead of copying help? (I have no idea.)

Comment: I'm guessing that you're on a unix-y system doing this. When you copy a file, even if you preserve the "modify" time, the "change" time is updated.  SBT, like all other build systems I know of, is doing a reasonable thing and assuming that because the files have changed that it needs to recompile.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, the staging area is used for the target files when the source folder is not read/write. Making the source folder read/write should fix this.

Comment: This is the real answer! The other response is a complete red herring. This is the real issue when you try to run sbt in the working directory in a CI server. If sbt cannot write to that working directory it falls back to staging inside its own home directory. The solution is to make sure that the sbt executing user has write permissions to the working directory

Comment: That's not 100% true. If you checkout a project via git in sbt, it will always be checked out to the staging folder. If you would like this to be in the project directory instead and not be shared by multiple builds, you need to change the staging folder, as in the answer from @Leif